# Ckeditor output saved in MySql and retrieved to front page

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I'm using the `ckeditor` on my site to format the content and saving the output of the editor in MySql. I have a problem when I fetch the content from the MySql then it is displaying the output with `bb code` as string not string for example

The value saved in MySql is

```
[b]hello my name is [/b] [color:#FF0000]Rohit[/color]
```

it is displaying the output on page is when I fetch

```
[b]some text[/b] [color:#FF0000]some text[/color]
```

I want the output *hello my name* in bold and *Rohit* in red color **:**
hello my name is Rohit

Is it possible?

Comment: ckeditor does not use bbcode unless you have the BBCode Plugin , it writes html\css

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line `extraPlugins : 'bbcode'` from your

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'best_moments',{ height: '40px',extraPlugins :'bbcode'
```

...and it would display the output as you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Will it format the text content without the extraPlugins : 'bbcode' that is in script?